# Multiple Facebook Like buttons referring same page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a page with like button assigned to it. I have some textual contexts on this page, I want to put a Facebook Like button under each text (I do not have different url for each text para on this page).

I want the count to be updated for the page also as user clicks on Like button under any text.

If you can tell me how to hide count near the Like button then also my problem is resolved.
Example: http://www.santabanta.com/trivia.asp?sms=1&catid=1

Comment: Can you use anchor links in your URL that you 'Like'?  Example:  http://yoursite.com/page.html#thing1, http://yousite.com/page.html#thing2, http://yoursite.com/page.html#thing3

Comment: Hi Teddy,
Thank you for your suggestion. This will work.
But I want to increase my page's Like count, when a user clicks as user clicks on Like button meant for texts on this page.

Answer (score 0):

You could subscribe to edge.create event and reload the buttons after a user clicks like.